# How can I create an interface library?

Tags: c, cmake, static-libraries

I have a static library that I want to use in different places of my c project. I'm using CMake as a build automation tool. CMake offers the possibility to add a property to a library, and the one I'm mainly interested in here is associating the header files of this library to it so that I do not have to add the path of the header file everywhere I'm using this library.

So, I have tried using an interface library, but when including it where I need it, the compiler can't find the reference to the function needed, without me manually including the path to them.

I have a C project that looks something like this:

```
project
 |
 |-------> app
 |           |----> include
 |           |       |----> a.h
 |           |
 |           |----> src
 |           |       |----> a.c
 |           |
 |           |----> CMakeLists.txt
 |
 |-------> external
 |           |----> lib
 |           |       |----> static_lib.a
 |           |
 |           |----> include
 |           |       |----> b.h
 |           |
 |           |----> CMakeLists.txt
 |
 |----> CMakeLists.txt
```

static_lib.a contains the compiled b.c file, where a function `void b();` is implemented and defined in the b.h header file. In order for me to easily add the static_lib.a in different library of my app folder, I created an interface library of `static_lib.a`, that also includes the properties of where to find its associated header. The `CMakeLists.txt` in the external folder looks like this:

```
add_library(b STATIC IMPORTED)

set_target_properties(b PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION lib/static_lib.a)

target_include_directories(b INTERFACE include)
```

Now, I'm trying to use this interface library `b` in my app folder:

`a.h` contains the following code:

```
void a();
```

`a.c` contains the following code:

```
#include "a.h"
#include "b.h"

void a() {
   b();
}
```

and the `CMakeLists.txt` of the `app/` folder looks like this:

```
file(GLOB_RECURSE SOURCES src/a.c)

add_library(app ${SOURCES} )

target_link_libraries(app PRIVATE b)

target_include_directories(app PUBLIC include)
```

The root CMakeLists.txt contains everything left for me to compiler the entire project, it's not really important here I believe.

Anyway, once I'm trying to compile now, I get an error that `a.c` file could not find the reference to the `b()` function:

```
a.c: fatal error: b.h: No such file or directory
  xx | #include "b.h"
```

Am I doing something wrong with my interface library? Is this not the way it's meant to be used?
The only way I get this to work, is by adding the `static_lib.a` directly in my app `CMakeLists.txt`, but then I also need to include the path of the header files:

```
file(GLOB_RECURSE SOURCES src/a.c)

add_library(app ${SOURCES} )

target_link_libraries(app PRIVATE b)

target_include_directories(app PUBLIC include ../external/include)
#                                                      ^
#                                                      |
#                                                I don't want this
```

This which is not really convenient, because again, my goal would be to be able to include it at different places in my project.

Comment: Yeah you get the error because there in fact is no b.h in the current directory. Try instead ../include/b.h

Comment: Hey @PromitheasNikou, that's exactly what I would like to avoid. Assuming I need to move my static library in an other directory or so, I would need to rewrite the path everywhere.  What I assumed is that `target_include_directories(b INTERFACE include)` would do that for me, so that I only have to include the `b` library in my other library without having to actually mention header path. Isn't there such an option ?

Comment: Well, you can always just put the headers and sources in the same folder (that's what i always do)

Oh, also, you could try writing <b.h> instead of "b.h" (I'm not so sure, I'm not familiar with cmake in particular but if i had to guess include directories may also mean diamond includes, not string includes (sorry i'm not very good at explaining))

Comment: In your current code, the library **target** `b` is **visible** in the `external/` subdirectory only. That is, when you use `target_link_libraries(app PRIVATE b)` in the `app/` subdirectory, CMake treats `b` as an option `-lb` for pass to the linker. For make IMPORTED target to have global visibility, specify `GLOBAL` keyword when create that target: `add_library(b STATIC IMPORTED GLOBAL)`.

Comment: Note also, that while some CMake **commands** accept **relative** paths, paths in the **properties** should always be **absolute**. Instead of `set_target_properties(b PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION lib/static_lib.a)` use `set_target_properties(b PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/static_lib.a)`

Comment: Thank you @Tsyvarev, the GLOBAL keyword fixed it all! I'm just wondering now: is this only needed for imported library ? Because I've created other libraries in my project, and never did I used this GLOBAL keyword before. Yet, it worked with the others. Any reason for that?

Comment: "is this only needed for imported library?" - Yes, GLOBAL option is applicable only when create an IMPORTED target. Every other target has global visibility unconditionally. For better understanding targets in CMake, you could read e.g. that [documentation page](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html).